# Get the Data of cell thats Dirty on RowUpdating Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I am using UltraWebGrid from Infragistics for grid functionality in my ASP.NET 4.0 Application. I have enabled inplace editing for few columns in the grid. I wrote the logic for this event as

```
protected void UltraWebGrid_RowUpdating(object sender, RowUpdatingEventArgs e)
```

in code behind. Along with this I want to know which cell in the row triggered this event, meaning Updating which field in the row triggered this event. I found we have a Row property for `RowUpdatingEventArgs` Class but that gets the entire row. I want to know what cell, its column name etc.. in the row was dirty that made this event happen.
Any useful pointers on this one?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to track this on your own and can see when a cell is updated by handling the client side AfterCellUpdate client side event.  In this event you will know what cell triggered the change and will need to store that information in a hidden field or possible a hidden column of the grid so that you can access it later

You can see all of the client side events for the UltraWebGrid in the online documentation:
http://help.infragistics.com/doc/ASPNET/2011.1/CLR4.0/?page=WebGrid_Client_Side_Events_CSOM.html